# Avoiding subquery for optimization

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I am trying to optimize a query and stuck. Any help appreciated. Basically there are two tables, one for people and another for events for the people. The structure is something like -

```
table 1 - people - columns - peopleid, name
table 2 - events - columns - event name, peopleid, description
```

I want to figure out the people with no events, without using a subquery. I was doing it with a subquery but the performance has degraded a lot and i need to optimize.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Show us your query, shows us the tables' definitions (with existing indexes). Either Subquery or a Join, the problem is probably on the indexing.

Comment: *Why* has the performance "degraded"? Instead of jumping to the conclusion that you need to eliminate the subquery, why not find out what's making it take too long (possibly via `EXPLAIN`ing a query) and address the root cause?

Comment: Check existing indexs fragmantation. Check missing columns and create non-cluster covering index.

Comment: @Borealid: in mysql subqueries cause performance issues in most cases, because of optimizer that cannot optimize them well. Even uncorrelated subqueries **always** are transformed into correlated. Thus I'd recommend to use subqueries **only** in case you perfectly know what optimizer will do in that particular case

Comment: @Thit Lwin Oo: makes no sense

Comment: @zerkms: Simple subqueries with `NOT IN` or `NOT EXISTS` usually behave as well as (or even better than) the `LEFT JOIN / IS NULL` equivalent in MySQL, with proper indexes.

Comment: @ypercube: `NOT IN` cannot be optimized by B-Tree indexes **by definition**. So doubtfully fullscan can be ever better than join that *uses* indexes on a huge table. The same with `NOT EXISTS`

Comment: Reference: [NOT IN vs. NOT EXISTS vs. LEFT JOIN / IS NULL: MySQL](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/) and [LEFT JOIN / IS NULL vs. NOT IN vs. NOT EXISTS: nullable columns](http://explainextended.com/2010/05/27/left-join-is-null-vs-not-in-vs-not-exists-nullable-columns/)

Comment: @ypercube: That's amazing and unbelievable. Thank you for the reference, I was so wrong

Comment: @zerkms: What you are right is that some subqueries can cause real performance problems in MySQL. I think mostly the `IN (SELECT ...)` ones, if the left side (not the subquery) is a big table. It's not optimized in the best way. Even worse with nested `IN` subqueries inside other `IN` subquery.

Comment: @zerkms Why no sense? For slow query, indexs are part of issues, of course other matters of table design, datatype etc. Why said so?

Comment: well i checked the indexes and each of the id columns are indexes. will debug further and let know anything i find. Thanks a lot for the help guys, really appreciate.

Comment: Please give us more information: original query, `EXPLAIN` output, table structure and index definition, and MySQL version.  It is well known that the MySQL query optimizer has some problems with this kind of queries and good advise dependends on the info you supply.

Comment: the original query was select * from people where peopleid not in (select peopleid from events)

the mysql version is 5.1.54

Comment: @Thit Lwin Oo: indexes fragmentation? o_O Non-clustered indexes? o_O

Comment: @zerkms I recommend to read SQL Server 2008 Query Performance Tuning Distilled [Apress Grant Fritchey and Sajal Dam]. It is one of the best book for performance tuning.

Comment: @Thit Lwin Oo: I do know what you're talking about but the question is about **MYSQL**. You know - mysql and sql server are **different** RDBMS

Comment: @zekms Yes, I know different RDBMS. My point is any RDBMS should have similar mechanism of indexing.. I just suggested some other possible of query slow. That's all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
   SELECT p.peopleid,
          p.name
     FROM people p
LEFT JOIN events e ON e.peopleid = p.peopleid
    WHERE e.peopleid IS NULL
```

Comment: This reduces the time by 6 seconds :). The original query I have is taking around 50 seconds to execute and with this it takes around 43.8 seconds. So it is an improvement. Still trying to optimize further. Thanks a lot for the answer. Accepting it as the correct one as I dont see another yet and it does what was asked in a way.

Comment: @pinaki: next time you ask something about db optimizations - please attach your **real** schema

Comment: i know it is frustrating, but company policies and all you know, make it impossible to share the real thing. I tried to make it as close to the real thing as possible though. Thanks for the effort